# How to rotate your angle to someones position (In lua)?

Tags: lua, angle, pitch

Let's say that we have function setAngle(x,y,z) which works perfectly.
Now we also have position of ourself and a chicken. How can we use setAngle() to aim the chicken? This would be done in an fps game? I have no idea on how to convert the positions to the angle... >.<

Comment: Way too vague to answer. If you have this setAngle function, read its documentation - it may be doing any number of things, for instance rotating around each axis in turn, in which case the coordinate orientation and order matter.. etc.

Comment: which coordinate system it is? what does setAngle() exactly do?

Comment: try to formulate your question a bit better. something like:
given two points, p1(x1,y1) and p2(x2,y2) - how do I get the angle between the two points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is math? Let be yourself at point

```
A(x, y, z)
```

and the chicken at

```
B(x, y, z)
```

`A` is part of plane `E`; its points satisfying the equation

```
a * x + b * y + c * z = d
```

Considering your game, `E` is possibly parallel to the `XY`-plane, so we have

```
E : c * z = d
```

Then, the angle enclosed by vector `AB` and the `XY`-plane is the arcsin of

```
c * ( B[z] - A[z] ) / ( mag(n) * mag(AB) )
```

where `mag(n)` is the magnitude of the surface normal of `E` resp. of the vector `AB`.

Considering your function, this might proof unnecessary, for it seems to me like adjusting things for you already.

Answer (score 0):

It is the aTan of the slope of the line between you and the chicken. Use aTan2 though, it will work better regarding vertical directions (Thanks lhf)

Comment: `atan2` will probably work better because it'll handle vertical directions.